# listing tree structure in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i need to list the category tree generated in category controller to the users add view to add them along to view to which category does the user belong to. here is my category code someone please help to find me the way to list them in users add.ctp or implement it in user model

```
public function admin_add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->ServiceCategory->create();
            if ($this->ServiceCategory->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The service category has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The service category could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $parents[0] = "[ No Parent]";
        $categoryList = $this->ServiceCategory->generateTreeList(null,null,null," -> ");
        if($categoryList){
            foreach($categoryList as $key=>$value):
                $parents[$key] = $value;
            endforeach; 
            $this->set(compact('parents'));
        }

    }
```

i need to implement this along with users so plz help if someone know how to do this

Comment: In what way does the code you've already got not work? Why can't you just call generateTreeList?

Comment: i want to call this in different model rather than category to list the category while the user register to opt the one they belong to

Comment: coz wen i call the tree simple by using call den i get the list but i am supposed to generate the tree structure of my category in the user form here is the code how i used the call in controller                      $categories = $this->User->find('threaded', array( 
    'order' => array('ServiceCategory.lft')) 
   );

Comment: plz help me m stuck in dis thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, here are the things that i need to add to my code

```
//controller
    $user_Id = $this->User->getLastInsertID();
                for($i=1;$i<=$this->request->data['User']['category_count'];$i++){
                $categories = $this->request->data['User']['category_id_'.$i];

                        if($categories>0){
                            $this->User->query("insert into provider_service_categories
 (user_id,service_categories_id)  values ('$user_Id','$categories')");

                        }   
                    }
$this->loadModel('ServiceCategory');
        $serviceCategories = $this->ServiceCategory->generateTreeList(null,null,null,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        //debug($serviceCategories);
        $this->set(compact('categories','serviceCategories'));

//view.ctp
$i =0;
        foreach($serviceCategories as $key=>$value){
            $i++;
            $cb = $this->Form->checkbox('category_id_'.$i, array('value'=>$key,'id'=>'category','class'=>'default'));
            echo  "<li>$cb $value &nbsp;</li>";
            }
        echo $this->Form->hidden('category_count',array('value'=>count($serviceCategories)));
```

thanx anyways

Comment: You could also use the [TreeHelper](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/) for this by the way.